# Calculating Strings in Java, tricky

Tags: string, calculator

I want to calculate Strings like:

"-4443-   +397"            // should return -4840

"  -8844443  /  -73897 "          //should return 119

" 4433   *    -7  "           // should return -31038

" +4   *    -5897  "          // should return -23588

[https://imgur.com/a/vzLix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oEMJ.png)

Its very hard and tricky, i dont how i should calcute the strings.
The problem are not removing the Whitespaces, its more how i should calculate the Strings above. :(

```
public static int calc(String input) {

    String noSpaces = "";
    int i = 0;

    while (i < input.length()) {
        if (input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            noSpaces = input.charAt(i);
        }
        i++;
 }
```

Comment: If you add spaces before the operators, you can use a Scanner to parse the string.

Comment: Ok, if your problem is not about the spaces, what is your exact problem by now? How do you want to solve the problem? What are the steps needed and an which step do you have a problem?

Comment: I think, your first problem is: How to extract signed numbers (operands) and their operators  from an equation (which is given as string) to compute the result?

Comment: probably, I search how to, but there comes something with regex. I dont know anything about regex. probably something that Johny said would work, i also tried to make something with charAt or substring. But it only works for one digit numbers.

Comment: Here's a simple way using `Scanner`: https://ideone.com/r3P0MH

Comment: Yeah, this calculator is very good calculator, but when I input a String like "4+4"(without space between op) its shows me a error. I can add everthing when there are spaces between the operators. Is there a way that i can also give a String without spaces between the ops. You did alot of work here, ty very much!

Comment: Here I have similar calculator my friend helped me with: https://ideone.com/1vYR75

Answer (score 0):

This only works for one Digit numbers

public class Calculator {

```
static int calc(String input) {
    String nsp = "";
    int nr1;
    int nr2;
    char op;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; input.length() > i; i++) {

        if (input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            nsp = nsp + input.charAt(i);
        }

    }

    if (nsp.charAt(0) == '+' || nsp.charAt(0) == '-') {
        nr1 = Integer.parseInt(nsp.substring(0, 2));
        op = nsp.charAt(2);
        if (nsp.charAt(3) == '+' || nsp.charAt(3) == '-') {
            nr2 = Integer.parseInt(nsp.substring(3, 5));
        } else {
            nr2 = Integer.parseInt(nsp.substring(3, 4));
        }
    } else {
        nr1 = Character.getNumericValue(nsp.charAt(0));
        op = nsp.charAt(1);
        if (nsp.charAt(2) == '+' || nsp.charAt(2) == '-') {
            nr2 = Integer.parseInt(nsp.substring(2, 4));
        } else {
            nr2 = Integer.parseInt(nsp.substring(2, 3));
        }
    }

    if (op == '+') {
        result = nr1 + nr2;
    }

    if (op == '-') {
    result = nr1 - nr2;
     }

    if (op == '*') {
        result = nr1 * nr2;
    }

    if (op == '/') {
        result = nr1 / nr2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

}